# invalid mysql query on insert

Tags: php, mysql

i have to convert a bad code to a better solution for calculating counts from our site.
i have a table that counts the number of times

the current table:

```
CREATE TABLE `hits_2011_12_5` (
  `count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

now i want to slowly migrate the new code to the old one but i have this error with the new code:

```
ana@localhost:test> insert into hits_2011_12_5 values (1,2,3,4,5);
ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

what can be the issue?

Comment: such a table table means "better solution"?

Comment: that is old structure, the old "expert" created over 1000 tables with only one column to count the requests etc... so i want to change that and use count(*) instead with a where clause for the date but now i need to migrate all the data into this table which is a pain so i created a php script instead of doing it manually but i got this error

Comment: Your question makes no sense. The current table is called "hits_2011_12_5" but your insert query uses a table called "log". You don't give us the schema for the "log" table so we can only guess at what the problem is.

Comment: yes the log is the new table sorry the hits_2011_12_5 is the old one

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use this:

```
ana@localhost:test> insert into hits_2011_12_5 values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5);
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 5  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

The query you tried requires 5 columns, not inserting 5 lines.